# Obtaining Solaris 10 patches

Tags: solaris, upgrade

I have a Solaris 10 server.  I've been trying to find from where I can download patches/updates.

The specific bug I'm running into (http://bugs.opensolaris.org/view_bug.do?bug_id=6551484) is reportedly fixed, according to that report:

```
Commit to Fix   s10u4_12
Fixed In    s10u4_12
Release Fixed    solaris_10u4(s10u4_12) , solaris_nevada(snv_70)
```

So far, all the potential Solaris patch download sites that Google returns all redirect to the My Oracle Support portal.  I signed up for that, but now I need an "Oracle Support Identifier".

According to the FAQ:

> After you log in with your SSO account, you must
>   register your Oracle Customer Support Identifiers (Support IDs) or your
>   Sun Contract Number. Most customers have only one Support ID. Your
>   Support ID is included in the welcome letter sent from Oracle. This is a
>   number similar to 3434354 that defines for Oracle the products you have
>   licensed for support. After you have registered your Support IDs, you
>   must be approved by the Customer User Administrator (CUA) for your
>   organization.

There is no paperwork, I have a SPARC machine with Solaris 10 installed on it.  Am I out of luck regarding getting it updated?

Comment: What revision of Solaris are you running? If it was fixed in u4, then it should be present in u9 (the current). If you aren't running u9 I would suggest upgrading to that first.

Comment: According to uname, all the version info I can see seems to be "snv_34".  I don't know how that translates to release version numbers.  Uname also seems to be saying that it's release 5.11, but I was assured it was Solaris 10!  (SunOS hostname 5.11 snv_34 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-1000)  However, whatever the release I'm still running into the bug that I highlighted above and would like to apply the fix!

Comment: Then I doubt you're running Solaris 10. It looks more like Solaris Express. Run `cat /etc/release` to check your exact version. Solaris 10u9 will include `Oracle Solaris 10 9/10 s10x_u9wos_14a` on the first line.

Comment: /etc/release says: Solaris Nevada snv_34 SPARC ... Assembled 22 February 2006

Comment: Then yes, you're running an old Solaris Express (development) release. As far as I know patches were never made available for that. I highly recommend upgrading to a current release, either Solaris 10 update 9 or Solaris 11 Express.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was actually just now on the phone with Oracle about an unrelated matter, and they've confirmed with me that it's now not possible to download any patches for Solaris outside of the Oracle support system (http://support.oracle.com/).

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Correct, it's not possible to get Solaris 10 patches with out a valid support contract.  However it appears you don't need Solaris 10 patches since you're running Solaris Express.

Answer (score 2):

Although the patchset is no longer available without a support contract, the full iso-image of Oracle Solaris 10 1/13 (includiung Update 11) still is available:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris10/downloads/index.html

Would it be possible to update the existing system from this iso-image?

Comment: If the poster was actually running Solaris 10, then yes, they'd be able to upgrade.  But as their comments revealed, they were actually running software from the OpenSolaris/Nevada/Solaris 11 family, and to downgrade from that to Solaris 10 requires a reinstall and losing newer features.

Answer (score 0):

Based on you running Solaris Express on SPARC, it appears you'd need to flip to Solaris 10, or more likely Solaris 11 which would be closer to Solaris Express (OpenSolaris) that you're using.

And since you're using a SPARC system, are you sure you don't have a valid support contract?  If so, you should have OS support as well.